# Looking for examples of doubling measures with references

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

I am looking for examples of doubling measures apart from the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{d}.$ Furthermore, when is the Lebesgue measure restricted on a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ a doubling measure, or when is the volume measure on a Riemannian manifold, a doubling measure? Please provide some references. I found a lot of folklore but is quite hard to find specific references.

Comment: A sufficient condition for volume measure on a connected Riemannian manifold to be doubling is that the Ricci curvature be nonnegative.  This is a consequence of the Bishop-Gromov comparison theorem.

Comment: Also, volume measure on any compact Riemannian manifold is doubling.

Comment: Maybe you are referring to asyntotically douling rather than doubling tout court.

Comment: I am happy with the answers. Thank you. Is there a reference for that first statement (about the Ricci curvature)?

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but for other viewers of this question: there is weighted $\mathbb{R}^n$ where the weight is in the Muckenhoupt $\mathcal{A}_p$ class

Answer (score 1):

Hausdorff measure restricted to affine subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an example.

The case of manifolds, you can consider spherical Hausdorff measure restricted to vertial homogeneus subgroups in the heisenberg group.

I do not think there is any need of a reference for these really simple examples.

Maybe if you esplain more what you need, rather than asking for non trivial examples with references, it may be easier to give a precise answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that these results may be trivial for your field, but if I am going to use it in mine, where people dont use doubling measures much, then it would be nice if I can have references even for those simple examples (or at least a place where the reviewer can see how ``natural" the definition of doubling measure is), that is why I asked.

Comment: ouh sorry I thought you were just looking for examples. Well as always one should take a look to Federer's book to get full generality (chapter 2, togheter with vitali type covering theorems).